# Converting London to Central time

Tags: php, date, datetime

Trying to convert London to central time. Here is the script I'm using:

```
$timestamp = date('Y-d-m H:i:s');

$dt = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $dt->format('r') . PHP_EOL;

$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $dt->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
```

And I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse
>   time string (2013-19-01 01:40:23) at position 6 (9): Unexpected
>   character' in
>   /home/filevanc/public_html/scripts/cpa/control/update.php:7 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/filevanc/public_html/scripts/cpa/control/update.php(7):
>   DateTime->__construct('2013-19-01 01:4...', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   /home/filevanc/public_html/scripts/cpa/control/update.php on line 7

I can't see what the unexpected character is since the timestamp looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your date is invalid unless there suddenly are 19 months. ;)

You meant to do this:

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or, better yet, do this:

```
// $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ,- don't need this anymore

$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```

Comment: Just for anyone who may stumble across this. I changed around the $timestamp variable to: date('Y-m-d H:i:s')